# Passing Double Quotes in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My web app requires double quotes to be passed within the dropdownlist for the ListItem Value property because a few of the database names begin with numbers.  Is this possible?

I tried "\"123db\"" and getting this error "this attribute name must be followed by an equal..."

```
<asp:ListItem Value="123db">123db</asp:ListItem>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around Value? Like this `<asp:ListItem Value='"123db"'>123db</asp:ListItem>`?

Comment: <asp:ListItem Value="&quot;123db&quot;">123db</asp:ListItem>

Comment: Thanks, both of these work.  I forgot to update my connection string to include quotes as well, since I use them there also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<asp:ListItem Value="&quot;123db&quot;">123db</asp:ListItem>
```

Since't it's HTML that get's rendered in the end of the day.

However, **I would advise strongly not to include quotes in your value** - value should be a programmatic string, and " is not a valid character in it.